# Access nested property, in a safe way

Tags: javascript

How to access a nested property, in a safe way (i.e. without throwing a TypeError)

```
(a.b) ? a.b.c : undefined
```

Is there a less verbose way, without using a framework ?

Comment: Is there a less verbose way using a framework?

Comment: Something like `a && a.b && a.b.c`? Not sure that counts as less verbose. But that will evaluate to `undefined` if `a`, `a.b` or `a.b.c` are undefined. Otherwise it'll evaluate to whatever `a.b.c` contains.

Comment: @MattBurland: I think that's the "verbose" way the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: since they were using the ternary operator, I thought they were thinking along the lines of `a ? a.b ? a.b.c : undefined : undefined` which I think is a lot harder to read.

Comment: In this particular case you can just do `a.b && a.b.c`.

Comment: https://github.com/letsgetrandy/brototype

Comment: @m59: That's amazing!